# Bootstrap carousel shows first image only even though it's sliding to the next ones

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, carousel, bootstrap-carousel

My bootstrap carousel includes 4 images. The sliding/carousel itself is working fine but somehow only the first picture is shown whereas when sliding to picture 2-4, the screen is only sliding to white space, showing the image descriptions.

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{{ asset('img/key-visuals/01-lh.jpg') }}" alt="First slide">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src"{{ asset('img/key-visuals/02-lx.jpg') }}" alt="Second slide">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src"{{ asset('img/key-visuals/03-os.jpg') }}" alt="Third slide">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src"{{ asset('img/key-visuals/04-sn.jpg') }}" alt="Fourth slide">
  </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="icon-prev left"></span>
</a>

<a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
  <span class="icon-next right"></span>
</a>
```

At the moment, only the first image (**01-lh**) is shown, but when e.g. putting the src from my second picture (**02-lx**) instead of the first one, that picture gets displayed but none of the others. and so on..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you forget to put equals to after `src` property of `img` tag

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{{ asset('img/key-visuals/01-lh.jpg') }}" alt="First slide">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{{ asset('img/key-visuals/02-lx.jpg') }}" alt="Second slide">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{{ asset('img/key-visuals/03-os.jpg') }}" alt="Third slide">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{{ asset('img/key-visuals/04-sn.jpg') }}" alt="Fourth slide">
  </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="icon-prev left"></span>
</a>

<a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
  <span class="icon-next right"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Bootstrap 4 but still relying on outdated Bootstrap 3 class names.  `item` should be `carousel-item` per Bootstrap's updated guidelines:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#example

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>

  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: with carousel-item, the carousel isn't working at all, no sliding etc. so that can't really be the solution :/

Comment: Once you've corrected the `src` issue pointed out by @Varsha you should re-acquaint yourself with BS4s structure so you're applying the correct class names.

Comment: you're right but how do I adjust it? it's not working with carousel-item

Comment: @sonja - the only reason I can think that it works with `item` but not `carousel-item` is that you're actually loading Bootstrap 3.  I assume you're using BS4 because you're using `img-fluid` instead of `img-responsive` as well as `d-block`.